# Windows 7: no adb.exe in task manager :: ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb.exe" and click 'Restart'

Tags: android-studio

When I run my application I get an alert:

> ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb.exe" and click 'Restart'"

By which application is not running on devices, no adb.exe is running in task manager.  I found several solutions but they didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

ABD is not responding often occurred while using Android Studio 1.5.1. Hope it will be fixed in next update

Now, You need to reinstall your **Android Studio** before that restart the system if it worked no prob otherwise do it on Studio.

Comment: Thanks @I_Droid for your response.. actually adb was blocked by another application, I uninstalled that application and solved my problem.

Comment: How did you find ABD blocked by another application?

Comment: Uninstall of padNet+ will solve your problem, try to connect to the android studio again.